# Which OS for docker

Tags: docker, coreos

I bought a server for experimenting with docker. Now I need an OS, that docker can run on it. Which OS would you recommended to me? CoreOs, RancherOS, etc.
How about service discovery?
I want to run my microservices on container, that is my target.

Comment: did you have a look at the [docker homepage](https://docs.docker.com/linux/)?

Comment: Yes, but  I am not sure, what should I use. So ubuntu is ok?

Comment: ubuntu is great to experiment, so is debian. whatever you choose as long as it's linux. CoreOS is a bit more involved to setup, so I'd leave that for later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Docker is compatible with Linux, Mac OS X, or Windows. I will prefer Linux as in Linux **your machine will act as a localhost and the Docker host**, in networking, localhost means your computer and the Docker client, the Docker daemon, and any containers run directly on your localhost while in Windows the docker daemon is running inside a **Linux virtual machine**. You will use the Windows Docker client to talk to the Docker host VM. Your Docker containers run inside this host.

Docker on Windows

[image: docker on windows]

Docker on Linux

[image: docker on Linux]

Comment: Docker is compatible with linux, period. For everything else (windows, mac os), you need to run docker in a linux VM.